# SwiftUI playing Lottie animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, lottie

I was playing with the Lottie animations, these days, but I have some trouble how to stop them from the View.

Here is my ContentView, where I am playing the animation. I have one button which shows the boolean value in real-time:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var isShowing : Bool = true

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
         Color.green.opacity(0.3)
        VStack {
            VStack {
                LottieDosi(isShowing: .constant(isShowing)){Text("")}
                Button(action: {self.isShowing.toggle()}) {
                    
                    Text("Button is \(String(isShowing))")
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
}
```

and here is my LottieView:

```
struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {

 @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
 @State   var name  : String

 var loopMode: LottieLoopMode = .loop
 var animationView = AnimationView()

 func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
   let view = UIView()

   animationView.animation = Animation.named(name)
   animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
   animationView.loopMode = .loop
   animationView.play()

   animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(animationView)

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
       animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
   ])

return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) {
    isAnimating ? animationView.play() : animationView.stop()
}
}

struct LottieDosi<Content>:  View where Content: View {

@Binding var isShowing: Bool
var content: () -> Content

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {

          LottieView(isAnimating: .constant(isShowing), name: "13728-sticker-4")
            .frame(width: 175, height: 175)
        
    }
}
}
```

I have a binding bool which has to change itself either to true or false, whenever I tap on the button. In other words, when I press the button I should be able to play and stop it. But somehow, this boolean value is not shared between the structs and the animation is constantly playing. I am new to swift UI, so I assume I am doing something very wrong, therefore I will appreciate some help.

[Here you can see my animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juanq.jpg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've almost got it. You need to construct a `Coordinator` so that you can access the values inside your `LottieView`. It's straight forward to do.

1. Create a `Coordinator` class that conforms to `NSObject`
2. Pass in your `LottieView`.
3. Add the function `makeCoordinator` to your `LottieView`
4. Create an instance of your `Coordinator` in the `makeCoordinator` function
5. In your `updateUIView` access the `animationView` from the `coordinator`.

> You shouldn't need a binding for the `isAnimating` as the `LottieView` is not passing any information back to your `ContentView`. You also don't need that `@State` for the `name`

Here is how I have gotten Lottie to play and pause in my apps. Note that some of the variable names are different to yours but it should be enough to get you to where you need to be.

```
import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    let filename: String
    let animationView = AnimationView()
    let isPaused: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)

        let animation = Animation.named(filename)
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.loopMode = .loop

        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(animationView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        ])

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) {
        if isPaused {
            context.coordinator.parent.animationView.pause()
        } else {
            context.coordinator.parent.animationView.play()

        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: LottieView

        init(_ parent: LottieView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```

My `ContentView` looks like the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isPaused: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LottieView(filename: "loading", isPaused: isPaused)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            Button(action: {
                self.isPaused.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text(isPaused ? "Play" : "Pause")
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Here it is working:

[image: Animation playing and pausing on button click]

Comment: Hey, one question. Do you know how can I play it before the view is loaded? Because I am fetching data from a server and I want to play the animation while the data is loading. Right now it only starts when the view is completely loaded on the screen. Thank you mate!

Comment: It really depends on how your are presenting the loading screen. Ideally you should have some state variable that determines the state of your screen (the main states are usually loading, loaded, error). How you handle those states and present the views based off of that can be quite complicated or trivial depending on your set up. I think it would not be possible to answer your question well in a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have by chance any example from your projects?

Comment: A short appendix: If you – like me – don't loop your animation but only play it once and want it to play again the next time the button is clicked, I adjusted the updateUIView "else" part to: `context.coordinator.parent.animationView.play { (_) in  context.coordinator.parent.isPaused = true }` so it's paused again automatically after the animation played through. :)

Comment: Thanks very much, the simpler play only versions of UIRepresentable over Lottie weren't working for play/pause.